# "Practical coinduction" over $\mathbb N_\infty$?

Tags: coinduction

I've just finished reading the paper [Practical Coinduction](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/Structural.pdf) by Kozen and Silva. What is the difference between induction over $\mathbb N$ and coinduction over $\mathbb N_\infty$?

From the paper, it seems that coinduction is almost the same as induction, but with more restrictions. In particular, it appears that most (or all) coinduction proofs over $\mathbb N_\infty$ are also valid induction proofs over $\mathbb N$.

The main restrictions the paper lists are *opacity* and *guardedness*. What examples are there of induction proofs over $\mathbb N$ that satisfy these properties (and are therefore valid coinduction proofs)? And what examples are there of induction proofs that don't satisfy these properties (and are therefore not valid coinductions)?